# Automate update columns in a view with trigger function in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, trigger, plpgsql

Im attempting to update several columns in a view very similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343075/update-multiple-columns-in-a-trigger-function-in-plpgsql/15351196#15351196). The difference is that Im combining in some cases up to 3 tables, and for each update on the view I would like the trigger to do an INSTEAD OF UPDATE on the appropriate table.

From the [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE) I've figured out how to update columns by hand, but with some views having up to 20 or 30 columns this will get tedious. I would like to automate the process similar to the previously mentioned post.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d63dc/2)

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE poi
(
  poi_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  col_a integer DEFAULT 0,
  col_b integer DEFAULT 0,
  col_c integer DEFAULT 0
 )
/

CREATE TABLE points
(
  poi_id integer REFERENCES poi(poi_id),
  col_d varchar(50),
  col_e varchar(50),
  col_f varchar(5)
 )
/

-- Insert some example values
INSERT INTO poi (col_a, col_c) VALUES(1,1)
/
INSERT INTO points (poi_id, col_d, col_e, col_f) 
VALUES(1, 'col d description', 'col e description', 'name')
/

CREATE VIEW poi_view as 
SELECT poi.poi_id, 
poi.col_a, 
poi.col_b, 
points.col_d,
points.col_e 
FROM poi
JOIN points
ON poi.poi_id=points.poi_id
/

-- Create Instead of Trigger 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION poi_view_update()
RETURNS TRIGGER as 
$$
BEGIN
  IF (OLD.col_a != NEW.col_a) THEN
    UPDATE poi SET col_a = NEW.col_a 
    WHERE poi_id = OLD.poi_id;
    IF NOT FOUND THEN RETURN NULL; END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
  END IF;
  RAISE NOTICE 'No update performed';
  RETURN NEW;
  END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
/

CREATE TRIGGER poi_update_trigger 
INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON poi_view FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE poi_view_update()
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from poi
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d63dc/2/0)**:

```
| poi_id | col_a | col_b | col_c |
|--------|-------|-------|-------|
|      1 |     1 |     0 |     1 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select * from points
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d63dc/2/1)**:

```
| poi_id |             col_d |             col_e | col_f |
|--------|-------------------|-------------------|-------|
|      1 | col d description | col e description |  name |
```

**Query 3**:

```
select * from poi_view
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d63dc/2/2)**:

```
| poi_id | col_a | col_b |             col_d |             col_e |
|--------|-------|-------|-------------------|-------------------|
|      1 |     1 |     0 | col d description | col e description |
```

**Query 4**:

```
UPDATE poi_view SET col_a = 0
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d63dc/2/3)**:

**Query 5**:

```
select * from poi_view
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d63dc/2/4)**:

```
| poi_id | col_a | col_b |             col_d |             col_e |
|--------|-------|-------|-------------------|-------------------|
|      1 |     0 |     0 | col d description | col e description |
```

**UPDATE 3/7/18**

In attempting to answer my own question, Ive decided to approach it as plainly as possible, by creating the appropriate variables, building a query, then simply using the EXECUTE command. So far I have

```
DECLARE
   v_schema  text := quote_ident(TG_TABLE_SCHEMA);
   v_name text := quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME);
   column_name text;
   t_schema text := 'my_schema';
   t_name information_schema.tables.table_name%TYPE;
 BEGIN
    column_name = ???
    t_name = SELECT DISTINCT table_name 
    FROM information_schema.view_column_usage 
    WHERE view_schema = v_schema 
    AND table_schema = t_schema 
    AND column_name = column_name;
```

My current issue is how do I find the column name from the original table the column came from?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem in a more manual way. It took some time to complete for all columns but at least it is done. Heres an example, of what I did.

```
-- update col_d
        IF (NEW.col_d != OLD.col_d) THEN
          UPDATE poi
          SET col_d = NEW.col_d
          WHERE poi_id = NEW.poi_id;
          RAISE NOTICE 'col_d was % , changed to %',OLD.col_d,NEW.col_d;
        END IF;
-- in case col_d is NULL
        IF OLD.col_d IS NULL AND NEW.col_d IS NOT NULL THEN
          UPDATE poi
          SET col_d = NEW.col_d
          WHERE poi_id = NEW.poi_id;
          RAISE NOTICE 'col_d updated NULL to %', NEW.col_d;
        END IF;
```